# Azure SAML setting Subject NameID

Tags: azure, saml, saml-2.0

Strangely, for some reason, I cannot set the Subject/NameID in SAML on my Azure instance.

It always seems to default to the Stock Microsoft GUID. We tried different Attribute Values, and transformations, but it seems to always default back to the Microsoft GUID.

```
<Subject>
    <NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent">qAQx8T4vIpuL866RU691ifJ0gObt564JKYWuEC80_U0</NameID>
    <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
        <SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="id-4fef566567e33c8abc6f23f08bd4dc4f6d8cc0b"
         NotOnOrAfter="2023-06-08T21:10:15.856Z"
         Recipient="https://idp.ngrok.com/saml/edghtsrt_2Qw4TKzV0wq7bwDqMntP6WLxaFB/acs"
    </SubjectConfirmation>
</Subject>
```

Maybe this update/change takes a long time, it's very strange. And in the past we know we were able to set the NameID to an email address (A Valid Email Address)

I've tried various User Attributes, even tried doing Transformations with mixed results.

[image]

Any suggestions ? I can't imagine people would not want to change the SubjectID.

Hopefully it's a Policy or Security setting we are missing.

Answer (score 0):

We recently had the same problem. Everythig looked fine under "Enterprise Application" > "Single sign-on" > "Attributes & Claims" in the Azure web UI. The claim configuration for "Unique User Identifier (Name ID)" showed "Name identifier format" as "Email address", but the SAML Assertion contained `<NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent">[...]</NameID>`.

In our case the problem was fixed by changing the "Name identifier format" to "Persistent" and saving the changes. Then we changed it back to "Email address". After that the SAML Assertion contained the correct NameID.

I found this issue which seems similar, even though configuration was created using terraform: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azuread/issues/846.